# how to integrate google map in mobile website

Tags: google-maps, mobile-website

I went through google maps website.I got code form there for Google map Api.But this is not working on my mobile.I think javascript is not working.What is exact way to integrate google map for mobile browser ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

An example using PhoneGap and jQuery Mobile is [here](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/mobile-web-development-with-phonegap/source/browse/#svn/tags/r1.2/com.mds.apg/resources/jqm/phonegapExample)

Answer (score 0):

Today, almost mid-end to high-end mobile web browser support javascript. I think you don`t need to afraid to implement google api on it. But there is an alternatve way using google static map, it showing image and use no javascript. you can try it out [here](http://code.google.com/intl/id-ID/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)